# Dynamically bound event not triggering when submitting form through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to capture the data from all the forms in a page. The events are bound dynamically.

```
formCapture: function () {
      console.log("formCapture");
      var formsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
      console.log(formsCollection);
      for (var i = 0; i < formsCollection.length; i++) {
        this.bindEvent(formsCollection[i]);
      }
    },

    bindEvent: function (formElement) {
      console.log("bindEvent");
      var $this = this;
      if (formElement.addEventListener) {
        formElement.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
           $this.collectData(e, $this)
        }, false);
      }
    },

    collectData: function (e, that) {
      // save form data here
    }
```

It works fine when the form is submitted by clicking on the submit button ( Default behaviour ).

But when I bind something like this on the form:

```
jQuery("#form-submit").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#test-form").submit();
    console.log("form has been submitted");
    window.location = "https://example.com";
  })
```

Where `#test-form` is the form name and `#form-submit` is the id of submit button the `collectData` function that is bound to it won't fire.

Is there a way to get the data from the forms without interrupting its flow?

Comment: Try making the `useCapturing` flag (the boolean passed to `addEventListener`) `true`.

Comment: Tried. But no use.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just use the submit function, but trigger the submit like:
jQuery("#test-form").trigger('submit');

Comment: That part won't be under my control. The form can be submitted in any possible ways. Normal submit or using jQuery.